# Magento 2 How to edit invoice PDF to change subtotals calculations

Tags: magento2, pdf

Magento2 How to edit invoice PDF to change subtotals calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You can override this file and do your change which you want in PDF

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/AbstractPdf.php
```